# Page not found: Running a php file on an Apache sever

Tags: php, apache

I get page not found error when I try to run my php file running on the root folder of my apache. Other php files run fine(anyway this is a magento based site). Is it because i transferred the file through FTP?
Can a server be configured not to run some specific files? How can i get round this? has is got something to do with .htacess?

Comment: I think more details are required. So you can access yourdomain.com/file1.php but not yourdomain.com/file2.php?? Do you have any .htaccess file in place that could be causing problems? Also make sure the file uploaded correctly, ie has a size greater than 0 in your FTP client.

Comment: Make sure you're requesting the correct URI. Pay attention to filename case sensitivity

Comment: @Ben @Phil:Thanks all: It was due to permission settings on the php file. I changed it to 644 and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you uploaded your file into the /www or /httpdocs subdirectory.
If so, check the permissions of your file.

Comment: It was due to permission settings on the php file. I changed it to 644 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Does the fiel have the same extension as the other php files that work.

ie. myfile.*php* or myfile.*php4*

The default config for apache specifies that php files have the extension "php4" as php version 3.0 and before are not compatible with the current versions. Usually the plain "php" extension is re-enabled but maybe not in your case.

Comment: Thanks all: It was due to permission settings on the php file. I changed it to 644 and it worked.